# upgrading a factory contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

What is the most efficient/optimal way to upgrade a factory contract? Let's say I have a factory contract which can generate 3 different child contracts, how can it be upgraded to be able to generate 5 different child contracts in the future instead of 3?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to deploy a new factory, and update every reference from the old factory to the new one. Whether that's doable, depends on your situation.

If you have a main contract which contains a reference (address) of the factory, you'll have to update that address.

Comment: Thanks henk, how can I update every reference? could you give an example of updating a reference